# How can Vim stop responding?

Tags: session, vim, terminal

With an intention to increment a number in a line in Vim, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. To my wonder Vim stopped responding! Later I realized that I had actually pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Can somebody please explain this behavior?

I've made some changes to the file, but not saved before vim stopped responding.

(Aside: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> decreases the next number on the line)

Comment: Try stty `-ixon` to disable that behavior.  It was once very useful, when scroll buffers were small and output was slow enough that you could see what was scrolling by.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You've stopped the terminal with `CTRL-S`. To resume, press `CTRL-Q`.
Btw, this is not VIM-specific, but rather terminal-specific.

Comment: Is it possible to disable this ?

Answer (score 4):

To disable the Ctrl-S/ Ctrl-Q completely from your terminal, add the following line to your `.bashrc` :

```
stty -ixon
```